# open external data base to odoo module

Tags: python, odoo

I just put my odoo module security so that people with an email and password can access different sections of my module but when I pass my module my partner does not see the sections due to security. My question is how can I open a database on another computer by transferring the database of my module and so it can open it with the data that I configure and so I can enter the module? The file that brings the odoo database brings the following elements: filestore, dump.sql and manifest.json.
Or they have another alternative so that other people who pass my module can open it with the user profiles that I have created.

Answer (score 0):

You can create data files with this information.
There can be simple CSV files, or more complicated xml files.

You have to put your configuration in the data files and distribute them with your module.

With a CSV file you can use, for example something like this:

```
id,name,model_id/id,group_id/id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_idea_idea,idea.idea,model_idea_idea,base.group_user,1,1,1,0
access_idea_vote,idea.vote,model_idea_vote,base.group_user,1,1,1,0
```

Save this in the file `security/ir.model.access.csv`, and add it in your `__manifest__.py` file under the `data` key.

For more examples, see https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/howtos/backend.html#security

Comment: I have that ready, the problem is that the person who passed my module can not see the sections of my menu because I already have the security for user profiles. I want to know how the person who passes my local module can enter with the users that I have created (email and password).